# JRuby is not working

Tags: java, ruby, jruby

I got the latest source code. I added the jruby-1.7.2/bin subdirectory path to $PATH.

Now when i run

```
$jirb
```

or

```
$jruby -v
```

I get the error: **"The Java class is not found: org.jruby.Main**

My Java version is 1.4.2

What am i missing?

Comment: I recommend using RVM (https://rvm.io/).

Comment: RVM can't be installed on root as far as i know

Comment: Yes, it can. Look at the 'multi-user' and 'mixed-mode' installation options. See https://rvm.io/rvm/install/#explained

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/index-jsp-138567.html => you should consider upgrading Java

JRuby 1.7+ only supports Java 6+ (see here : http://www.jruby.org/2012/10/22/jruby-1-7-0.html)